# Swift scientific notation in base 16

Tags: swift, syntax, scientific-notation

I'm new in Swift language and playing with it. I know in most languages `1.5e3` means `1.5 * 10 ^3` and this is true in Swift. However, when it comes base 16, I have difficulty in understanding it. Below are 2 examples, hope someone can explain what they are:

```
println(0x12e3)
println(0x12p3)
```

The results are:

```
4835
144.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example is not using scientific notation - because `e` is a valid digit in hexadecimal, this is the number `12E3`, which is 4835 in decimal.

```
(1 * 4096) + (2 * 256) + (14 * 16) + (3 * 1) = 4835
```

The second example is the hex number `12` (18 in decimal) multiplied by a binary exponent (2 ^ 3), i.e. 8.

```
8 x 18 = 144
```

This notation is described in the Swift [language documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).